# Entry point not found error reported when calling tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell

Tags: tensorflow

Looking for a solution to the following error, encountered while using TensorFlow:

```
Python version = 3.5.0

Have I written custom code --> No
OS Platform and Distribution --> Windows 10
TensorFlow installed from --> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
TensorFlow version --> 1.8.0-gpu
Bazel version --> NA
CUDA/cuDNN version --> 9.0
GPU model and memory --> GeForce GTX 960M, 3GB
Exact command to reproduce --> See below

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons) # Errs out here
```

Error message:

```
"The procedure entry point
?AddCleanup@Arenalmpl@internal@protobuf@google@@QEAAXXEPEAXP6AX0@Z@Z could 
not be located in the dynamic link library 
C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\contrib\data_dataset_ops.so"
```

[image: Error dialog window]